# I forgot where I died the last time

Tags: dark-souls

I was scouting random paths yesterday and got mobbed by a bunch of strong enemies. Today I don't remember where they finally got to kill me. I had a ton of souls and humanity on me and it'd be a shame to lose it.

Is there any way to find out where I last died?

Comment: no. you can look at maps/guides and see if something refreshes your memory.

Comment: You mean like a direction marker or something? There is nothing like that. Can you maybe at least describe what type of enemies killed you and which zone were you exploring?

Comment: If you popped into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) I may be able to help you figure out where you were at when you died.

Comment: I figured it out. I looked into my inventory and found a peculiar item which I remembered where I found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no way in-game way to lead you to where you bloodstain is. If you can't remember where you died last then your only option would be to see if you can figure out the area you were at by reading guides or watching videos to see if anything sounds/looks familiar. I find [this wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/) to be very helpful, and it contains a list of [enemies](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/enemies) and [areas](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/areas). Looking through there may help you figure out where you were when you died.